# exchange api push notification response

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using exchange managed API and using push notification.
I am using below code

Uri uri = new Uri("http://domain.io/MyPage.aspx");

PushSubscription ps = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(folder, uri, 1, "", EventType.Created, EventType.Modified, EventType.Deleted);

Now i get a hit on domain.io/MyPage.aspx when i change a event from calendar.
But now how i process that response ?
There is limited value in request header.
how could i know that which calendar, which service this request come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer. Using API Call is more simple.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ExchangeCalendar()
    {
        string itemId = string.Empty;
        string subscriptionId = string.Empty;
        string pushResponse = "OK";
        string RESPONSE_OK = string.Empty;

        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        string eventData = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(eventData);

        subscriptionId = GetNodeValue(doc.GetElementsByTagName("t:SubscriptionId"));
        itemId = GetNodeValue(doc.GetElementsByTagName("t:ItemId"));
        calendarId = GetNodeValue(doc.GetElementsByTagName("t:FolderId"));

        RESPONSE_OK = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\"><soap:Body><SendNotificationResult xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\"><SubscriptionStatus>" + pushResponse + "</SubscriptionStatus></SendNotificationResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(RESPONSE_OK, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In very basic terms, after the `SubscribeToPushNotifications` call returns the `PushSubscription` there will be a subscription id that links the folder you subscribed to.  Any notifications for that folder will contain the subscription id and the ItemId, as well as the type of notification, New, Changed, Moved, etc.  You will need to maintain some kind of mapping of subscription id-to-folder, and then call EWS via GetItem to find the item in question.

Comment: Thanks pjneary.  But my question that how i get the values from that notification. When ever a change in calendar, ews api call my url. now in which variable these value are.  I am using doing code in C# and i also check the request.header, but there also no info..  Please help